# Populate gridview with results of a SQL Server stored procedure that returns multiple recordsets

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple recordsets. It can be 1 recordset, 2 recordsets, or more. I don't know how many RS will come back.

Here at stackoverflow I found the below sample

```
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnection").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACTNbr", tbACTNbr.Text.ToString.Trim)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WTHNbr", tbWTHNbr.Text.ToString.Trim)
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_search_def"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    conn.Open()
    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
'The next part is what I found here at stackoverflow
While Reader.Read() OrElse (Reader.NextResult() And Reader.Read())
  For i As Integer = 0 To Reader.FieldCount - 1
    Response.Write(Reader(i).ToString())
    Response.Write(" ")
  Next
  Response.Write("<br />")
End While
```

The above `response.write`'s show the data I need perfectly. But I need to put that into a Gridview. i.e. I need to put the results of the stored procedure (and all of its result sets) into one gridview.

My gridview is set to `AutoGenerateColumns = "true"`.

I've tried:

```
myGridview.DataSource = Reader
myGridview.DataBind()
```

And of course I only get one of the recordsets.

The results of the stored procedure are all formatted the same - same number of columns, headers, and so on.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I've been trying to figure this out, but give up and now I am asking here.

I am new to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use DataAdapter to fill DataSet instead of DataReader**, that you can easily bind to your gridview as shown below:

```
    Dim DS As DataSet
    Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim MyDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter

    'Create a connection to the SQL Server.
    MyConnection = New SqlConnection("server=(local);database=pubs;Trusted_Connection=yes")

    'Create a DataAdapter, and then provide the name of the stored procedure.
    MyDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("GetAuthorsByLastName", MyConnection)

    'Set the command type as StoredProcedure.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    'Create and add a parameter to Parameters collection for the stored procedure.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@au_lname", _
   SqlDbType.VarChar, 40))

    'Assign the search value to the parameter.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@au_lname").Value = Trim(txtLastName.Text)

    'Create and add an output parameter to Parameters collection. 
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RowCount", _
    SqlDbType.Int, 4))

    'Set the direction for the parameter. This parameter returns the Rows returned.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@RowCount").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    DS = New DataSet() 'Create a new DataSet to hold the records.
    MyDataAdapter.Fill(DS, "AuthorsByLastName") 'Fill the DataSet with the rows returned.

    'Get the number of rows returned, and then assign it to the Label control.
    'lblRowCount.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count().ToString() & " Rows Found!"
    lblRowCount.Text = MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(1).Value & " Rows Found!"

    'Set the data source for the DataGrid as the DataSet that holds the rows.
    Grdauthors.DataSource = DS.Tables("AuthorsByLastName").DefaultView

    'Bind the DataSet to the DataGrid. 
    'NOTE: If you do not call this method, the DataGrid is not displayed!
    Grdauthors.DataBind()

    MyDataAdapter.Dispose() 'Dispose of the DataAdapter.
    MyConnection.Close() 'Close the connection.
```

[How to call SQL Server stored procedures in ASP.NET by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574)

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind the GridView to one result set. For example, binding the `GridView` to a `DataSet` containing several DataTables will only show the data in the **first** `DataTable`.

Since all the result sets returned by the proc have the same schema, you need to merge them and bind the result set to the `GridView`.

Example:

```
//Assumes your proc returns a dataset with more than one datatable
//Notice how all datables are merged into the first one [0]
for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[i]);  
}

grid.DataSource = ds;
grid.DataBind();
```

Or equivalently:

```
grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];//this DT has everything
grid.DataBind();
```

The grid will display all rows from all the datatables

When the DataTables have different schema, the merged DataTable will have all the columns from all the DataTables.

For example, mergind a `DataTable` with a column called `Col1` with another `DataTable` with a column called `Col2` will result in something like this:

```
  +-----+------+
  |Col1 | Col2 |
  ------+------+
  |val1 |  null|
  +-----+------+
  |null |  val2|
  +-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to a DataTable.  A DataSet can hold multiple tables.

[DataSet.Tables Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using @Kapil and @Icarus replies, I was able to get this to work.
Thanks for taking the time to help.  It pointed me in the correct direction.

This is what I ended up with:

```
  Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim DS As DataSet
    Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim MyDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim msg As String = ""

    'Create a connection to the SQL Server.
    MyConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("msSQLdb").ConnectionString)

    'Create a DataAdapter, and then provide the name of the stored procedure.
    MyDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_search_all_SQLservers", MyConnection)

    'Set the command type as StoredProcedure.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    'Create and add a parameter to Parameters collection for the stored procedure.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ACTNbr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10))
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@WTHNbr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15))

    'Assign the search value to the parameter.
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@ACTNbr").Value = tbACTNbr.Text.ToString.Trim
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@WTHNbr").Value = tbWTHNbr.Text.ToString.Trim

    'Create a new DataSet to hold the records.
    DS = New DataSet()
    'Fill the DataSet with the rows returned.
    MyDataAdapter.Fill(DS, "proc_results")

    'Set the data source for the gridview as the DataSet that holds the rows.
    gv.DataSource = DS.Tables("proc_results").DefaultView
    For i = 1 To DS.Tables.Count - 1
      DS.Tables(0).Merge(DS.Tables(i))
    Next

    msg = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count & " rows found"
    gv.Caption = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count & " rows found"
    gv.DataSource = DS

    'Bind the DataSet to the DataGrid. 
    'NOTE: If you do not call this method, the DataGrid is not displayed!    
    gv.DataBind()
    If gv.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
      gv.Visible = True
    Else
      msg = "No data found"
    End If

    MyDataAdapter.Dispose() 'Dispose of the DataAdapter.
    MyConnection.Close() 'Close the connection.
    DS.Dispose()
    lblMsg.Text = msg
  End Sub
```